# How to plot BER Vs SNR curve for binary data

Tags: matlab, plot, binary

I have two vectors of dimension (130,1).One for the transmitted data and the other the received data. Using the following code I have obtained the BER and the number of errors in the vector. The problem is I have no idea how to proceed with plotting the BER vs SNR curve. Though the SNR can be varied from 1to 30 in steps of 1, the BER while plotter doesnt seem to change and im getting a straight line instead of a waterfall curve. Please help, Thanks in advance.

```
clc
clear all
close all

A = 'sample-25-4-18.xlsx';
sheet1 = 1;
sheet2 = 2
Range = 'A1:AN140';
B = xlsread (A ,sheet1, Range);
C = xlsread (A ,sheet2, Range);

N = 10^4 % number of bits or symbols
rand('state',100); % initializing the rand() function
randn('state',200); % initializing the randn() function

% Transmitter
Eb_N0_dB = [-3:10]; % multiple Eb/N0 values

for ii = 1:length(Eb_N0_dB)

   % counting the errors
   nErr(ii) = size(find([B - C]),1);

end
simBer = nErr/N; % simulated ber
theoryBer = 0.5*erfc(sqrt(10.^(Eb_N0_dB/10))); % theoretical ber

% plot
close all
figure
semilogy(Eb_N0_dB,theoryBer,'b.-');
hold on
semilogy(Eb_N0_dB,simBer,'b*');
axis([-3 10 10^-5 0.5])
grid on
legend('theory', 'simulation');
xlabel('Eb/No, dB');
ylabel('Bit Error Rate');
title('Bit error probability curve for BPSK modulation');
```

The plot looks as below.

[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are plotting in logarithmic scale, are you sure 100% that the simulation is a straight line? it can also be changing very little

Comment: yes sir, Its a straight line and thats why its confusing.